# Настройка модема, установка проги NoIP

Tags: сеть

1. Установил прогу NoIP, создал доменное имя, по которому можно будет подключиться, но когда захожу по url адресу, то попадаю на мой модем, а не на компьютер. Не очень понимаю, как пробросить порты, чтоб при обращении на этот адрес попадали на компьютер, а не на модем. Если кто может, напишите пожалуйста, что делать или где почитать.
2. И ещё вопрос (это в другой сети), если сеть типа `[белый айпи]----[10.63.3....]-----[192.168.1....])` как мне достучаться до компьютера, в сети 192.168.1... -здесь я ничего "пробрасывать не могу" т.к. оборудование не моё? Может работать с Hamachi (но опять же, тогда надо устанавливать её везде).

Answer (score 1):

Только с помощью хамачи.

Модем - это роутер ? Нужно во вкладке Port Forward настроить порты. На форуме уже были темы  - полистайте.